# Quickest way to access all nested values from object in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs, foreach, unique

In AngularJS I have an object of thousands of records from a JSON API call. I need to make a new array of just one specific key from each record ("topic"), resulting in an array of unique values only. Is a foreach loop the only way to do this? For example:

Data array (arr):

```
{
"id": 1,
"number": 2,
"section": "xx",
"importance": "high",
"applicability": "General",
"text": "some text here",
"topic": 
    {
        "id": 30,
        "title": "Gender and Diversity"
    }
 },
{
"id": 2,
"number": 2.1,
"section": "xx",
"importance": "high",
"applicability": "General",
"text": "some text here",
"topic": 
    {
        "id": 31,
        "title": "Health and Safety"
    }
 }, ...
```

I would like an array of just the topics from thousands of records, like this :

```
"topic": 
{
    "id": 30,
    "title": "Gender and Diversity"
},
"topic": 
{
    "id": 31,
    "title": "Health and Safety"
},..
```

Is there a better (quicker) method to create this list than what I currently have, a foreach loop with if statements, followed by a filter of unique values?:

```
var topics = function (arr) {
            var topics = [];
            angular.forEach(arr.data, function (ts) {
                angular.forEach(ts.topic, function (t) {
                    if (t.title) {
                        this.push(t);
                    }
                }, topics);

            });

            // Filter the unique values
            var elementId = [];

            var uniqueTopics = topics.filter(el => {
                if (elementId.indexOf(el.id) === -1) {
                    // If not present in array, then add it
                    elementId.push(el.id);
                    return true;
                } else {
                    // Already present in array, don't add it
                    return false;
                }
            });

            return uniqueTopics;

        };
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might help.

```js
var data = [
{
"id": 1,
"number": 2,
"section": "xx",
"importance": "high",
"applicability": "General",
"text": "some text here",
"topic": 
    {
        "id": 30,
        "title": "Gender and Diversity"
    }
 },
{
"id": 2,
"number": 2.1,
"section": "xx",
"importance": "high",
"applicability": "General",
"text": "some text here",
"topic": 
    {
        "id": 31,
        "title": "Health and Safety"
    }
 }
];

console.log(
  data.map(d => { return { "topic": d.topic }; })
);
```

```js
var data = [
    {
    "id": 1,
    "number": 2,
    "section": "xx",
    "importance": "high",
    "applicability": "General",
    "text": "some text here",
    "topic": 
        {
            "id": 30,
            "title": "Gender and Diversity"
        }
     },
    {
    "id": 2,
    "number": 2.1,
    "section": "xx",
    "importance": "high",
    "applicability": "General",
    "text": "some text here",
    "topic": 
        {
            "id": 31,
            "title": "Health and Safety"
        }
     }
    ];

    console.log(
      data.map(d => d.topic)
    );
```